# Unable to fetch dictionary from decoder

Tags: swift, decodable

I need to fetch the entire dictionary as string for the key "content".I am receiving it as nil.I ve tried using [String:Any] throws exception that any cannot be confirmed to decodable

```
public static func getModelObjects<R: Codable>(_ type: R.Type, from data: Any?) -> [T]? {
        var mappedObjects: [T]?
        if let dataAsDic = data as? JSONDictionary {
            let decodedObject = decodableData(type, dictionaryData: dataAsDic)
            mappedObjects = [decodedObject] as? [T]
        } else if let dataAsArray = data as? [JSONDictionary] {
            var objects: [R] = []
            for dataAsDic in dataAsArray {
                guard let decodedObject = decodableData(type, dictionaryData: dataAsDic) else {
                    return nil
                }
             objects.append(decodedObject)
            }
            mappedObjects = objects as? [T]
        }
        return mappedObjects
    }

    private static func decodableData<R: Codable>(_ type: R.Type, dictionaryData: JSONDictionary) -> R? {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionaryData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(type, from: jsonData)
                return decodedData
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }

    public class Configuration: CacheableEntity, ConfigurationStorageProtocol, Codable {
          public dynamic var configurationID: String!

            /// Version of configuration
            public dynamic var version: String!

            private var storedConfigDict: JSONDictionary?

            private var storedConfigData: Data?
              // Holds complete configuration as string

    dynamic var configString: String? 

                /// Codable keys to confirm Codable protocol
                private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                    case configurationID = "id"
                    case version
                    case name
                    case content
                }

            public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                super.init()
                let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                self.name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
                self.configurationID = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .configurationID)
                self.version = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .version)
                self.configString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .content)
            }

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var  container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try? container.encode(configurationID, forKey: .configurationID)
    try? container.encode(version, forKey: .version)
    try? container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
  }
}
```

In the below json i need to fetch the entire content as string.I have tried using [String:Any] but it crashes mentioning any cannot be conformed to decodable.

```
"name": "sdkconfig",
    "id": "gma_5.0_ios_sdkconfig_1.0_us",
    "version": "1.0",
    "modifiedDateTime": "2017-06-15T08:15:25.304Z",
    "content": {
        "configName": "sdkConfig",
        "configVersion": "1.0",
        "enabled": {
            "modules": [
                        "account",
                        "nutrition",
                        "restaurant",
                        "offer",
                        "ordering",
                        "favorite"
                        ],
            "socialAccounts": [
                               "facebook",
                               "google",
                               "twitter"
                               ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `encode(to:)` method?

Comment: @justintime updated

Comment: Please show how you're using the func `decodableData`.

Comment: @justintime Updated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the way you're doing. But this is how I got it working.
Define your class something like this.

```
    struct Configuration: Codable {

        var content: String?
    }
```

Property name and the name in json must be same. ('cotent' in this case).
Now parse your json string something like this.

```
    var configuration = JSONDecoder().decode(Configuration.self, from: "your json string")
```

Comment: can you provide an example fitting my above context..I have updated my example with my JSONDecoder

Comment: Where have you defined your configString? I can't find it in your class.

Comment: Another thing which I noticed in your JSON string, the value of the 'content' is not a string, because it is not wrapped in double quotes. You can try to embed the value of content in double quotes and see if that works.

Comment: I am receving the above from my api.I have pasted a partial resonse and missing a few variable to know the gist of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Athough the flow and structure of your code is not clear as others have pointed out,
but seems you're wanting to encode the `JSONDictionary` you have as a `String` into `configString` property.
I see that you're decoding `configString` in `init(from decoder: Decoder)`,

```
self.configString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .content)
```

but you're not encoding it, your encode method should be:

```
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var  container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try? container.encode(configurationID, forKey: .configurationID)
    try? container.encode(version, forKey: .version)
    try? container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    if let jsonStr = String(data: storedConfigData, encoding: .utf8) {
        try? container.encoder(jsonStr, forKey: .content)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I ignored this info from your question:

> I have tried using [String:Any] but it crashes mentioning any cannot
>   be conformed to decodable

Basically decoder doesn't know how to decode `Any`, you need to provide a specific type, try the following in your `init(decoder:)`,

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.configurationID = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .configurationID)
        self.version = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .version)
        if let configDict = try? container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .content) {
            self.configString = String(describing: configDict)
        }
    }
```

**OR**

Above won't work if your content is a heterogenous dictionary,
Since you already have dictionary data you can use it to directly get content, like so,

```
config.configString = String(describing: dictionaryData[Config.CodingKeys.content.rawValue] as! JSONDictionary)
```

Comment: I am not using encoding.Its a dead code.I am trying the decode the corresponding json  to fetch the dictionary from "content".I have pasted a partial code to get the gist of the issue..

Comment: Updated answer.